# Visual Studio C++ Implement Interface

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I know in Visual Studio, when programming in C#, if I specify that a class implements an interface, I can right click on the interface and "Implement Interface", which will auto-magically populate my class with the appropriate method signatures.

EDIT: Let me apologize for the vagueness of the original question. I'm looking for a quick easy way to get Visual Studio to do the dirty work of implementing multiple COM interfaces, i.e. generating the method signatures/stubs in the implementing class.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: You'll first have to explain what exactly you mean by "interface" and "implementing interface" in VC++ context. Do you mean .NET interfaces and C++/CLI? COM interfaces in ATL or MFC projects? Pure C++ "interfaces", which are just abstract classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces don't exist in C++.

The level of IDE support for the language is one of C#'s perks.  Visual C++ is quite a different beast indeed.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not support interfaces, so Visual Studio does not supply a "Implement Interface" feature when you're working in C++.